# jQuery Ajax call returning '[object XMLDocument]'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML page which I want to populate using Ajax.  I've copied code from other pages, (which are all in PHP, and I'm not sure if that matters), and it's returning `[object XMLDocument]`.  In the other pages (the PHP ones) I get whatever I printed out in the routine.

Here's what I have:

index.html -

```
<html> ... </html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 getSplashHelpVideos();
});
</script>
```

In the javascript file -

```
function getSplashHelpVideos() {
 $.ajax({ 
   url: "include/get_help_videos.php",
   type: "POST",
   success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
   }
 });
 return;
}
```

In get_help_videos.php (obviously this is just temporary code to try to figure out how this works) -

```
<?php
 session_start();
 echo 'OK';
 return;
?>
```

So I was expecting (and wanting) it to pop up an alert saying 'OK', which is what it would do in my other routines, but it pops up `[object XMLDocument]` instead.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it best to live with it, and parse the `XMLDocument`?

Comment: Why not force type? `{ dataType: 'text' }`

Comment: what browser is this in?

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I tried forcing the type, and it made no difference.  I'm in Firefox.

Answer (score 26):

You need to include the datatype parameter on you AJAX call to indicate that you are simply expecting a text response:

```
function getSplashHelpVideos() {
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "include/get_help_videos.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that hasn't made any difference.  I still get the contents of get_help_videos.php back.

Comment: By 'contents of x.php' do you mean you get the actual PHP code of the page returned? If that's the case PHP is not being interpreted correctly by your server and it's a settings issue. This would also explain why jQuery's ajax function automatically determined the response type was XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below. I've just tested it on Firefox 15.0.1 and it works well:

```
$.post("include/get_help_videos.php", function(data)
{
    alert(data);
}, "text");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set the content type of **response** to **text/html** first then say **echo "ok"** like this:

```
header('Content-type: text/html');
```

I got the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410220/different-message-in-different-browser) and it solved this way only, since when we does not specify the content type of the response every browser treats the response in different format as and so.

Answer (score 0):

change your response type to `html/text` in get_help_videos.php file

Answer (score -1):

You just need to tell the datatype(which direct the browser you are expecting response in the mentioned format only,e.g.: "text" format) .
In this case I tested this in firefox and mozilla.and it works.. :)

Check the Response in firefox/Mozilla - you can also verify the coming response after ajax request... follow the below steps-- 
press F12 in firefox/mozilla --> go to "Console" tab --> go to "Response" sub tab. :)

```
function GetEmployeeListWS_REST() {        
            jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/RESTDemo/rest/hello/helloXML",
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",                
            dataType: "text",
             crossDomain: true,
            //data: packet,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(xhr + ' ' + textStatus + '' + errorThrown); },
            success: function (response, status, xmlData) {

                $("#EmployeeDetailsWs").text(response);                    
            }
        });

    } // ends : fun()
```