# Different Message in Different browser

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am working with the jquery post module....

```
$('#btnAuthentication').click(function(){
    $.post('callc2dm?param=authentication', function(data) {
      alert(data);
    });
});
```

The alert show correctly in **Chrome,IE** but not in ***firefox***
for chrome it shows the value as "From Server authentication" which is correct as I am just checking whether data is coming from server or not but when I run the same code in FireFox it shows a message like this **[object XMLDocument]**

Why is it so?

Thanks in advance.............

Comment: This is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810525/jquery-ajax-returning-object-xmldocument ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I get it fixed , I am not setting the **content type** when sending back the response,so different browsers are seeing the content differently, and showing the **message** as and so...........

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
```

and it solved my issue.Now every browser is showing the message as it is required to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this code.

```
 $('#btnAuthentication').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'callc2dm',
     data: (
       { param: 'authentication' }
     ),
     success: function(data){
       alert(data);
     }
   }); 
 });
```